# How to check if element's "before" pseudo-selector has a specific style associated with it?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

If I have an element with the following style rule:

```
.element::before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white, inset 0 0 0 12px tomato;
}
```

How can I select this element with Javascript, and check if it contains that specific `box-shadow` style? Thanks.

Can I do something like this?

```
const element = document.querySelector('.element::before').hasStyle('      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white, inset 0 0 0 12px tomato;');
```

Comment: Generally speaking it's not good practice to base your application logic on whether styles are present. Use a class on the parent element or some other means of tracking more explicitly.

Comment: @isherwood, I completely agree. Unfortunately, the client is using a 3rd party widget that is poorly built and I'm forced to write the logic this way.

Comment: Fair enough. Hopefully Barmar's duplicate helps. If not, let us know.